# Error occurred: Please Check "Store archive output"

Tags: raspbian, arduino

I am trying to download and install the Arduino IDE on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Vol 2. I have followed the tutorials and attempted to download the Arduino 32 arm bit tar file on the pi. I am attempting to extract the file but every time I do attempt it I get an error telling me to check the "store archive output." I have not been able to find that output and I have not been able to solve this problem can anyone help?

Comment: Also, getting the error "xarchiver 0.5.4.14 'An error occurred while accessing the archive:'"

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. Instead edit the question and add information there. Also please add the answers of this: what tutorials? What command gives you the error message? What error message exactly? Where do you get the Arduino 32 arm bit tar file?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, and I didn't find the solution to the problem above: but I know what you are talking about and found a workaround.

The archive manager doesn't work well on Raspbian. I have seen this on a few units and it's a pain to deal with. There are also a lot of post like this with the issue, but no resolution.

SOLUTION: Try using the terminal and the command `tar -xf Name_of_tar.tar.gz`. That should work.